# rxtools build error on OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: rxtools, macos-snowleopard, rosmake, wxwidgets, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run "rosmake rxtools" - I get:

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/ros/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp:6149: error: expected `)' before 'void'
/Users/tobymartin/ros/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp: In function 'void* _p_wxFileDialogTo_p_wxDialog(void*)':
~/ros/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp:6155: error: 'wxFileDialog' was not declared in this scope
~/ros/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp:6155: error: expected primary-expression before 'void'
....etc.

The log file says:

~/ros/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp:2739:34: error: wx/wxPython/wxPython.h: No such file or directory
~/ros/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rosout_panel_swig_generated.cpp:2740:35: error: wx/wxPython/pyclasses.h: No such file or directory
...etc.

I have "ports" installed : py26-wxpython and wxWidgets-python...in, I assume, is the the standard /opt/local/include/wx-2.8/wx/wxPython dir.

Looking at the CMakefile - I see "find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)" and later "include_directories(${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})"...I assume this environment variable is set by the "find_package" command.

But still, rosmake can't seem to find those headers.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11000/rxtools-build-error-on-osx-snow-leopard/) by [tbmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/989/tbmartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2011-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nevermind - I found a solution.  I created a symlink in /opt/local/include  wx@->wx-2.8/wx

with the command: sudo ln -s wx-2.8/wx wx

---

Originally posted by [tbmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/989/tbmartin/) with karma: 16 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0